# How do I make so when user moves the camera it doesn't go beyond the scene borders?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

1. How do I make so when I move the camera(with touch) it doesn't go beyond the scene borders?
2. How do I move the camera with touch so it moves strictly with scene parts, like slides(swipe-first slide, another swipe-another slide) with not going beyond the borders of the scene?

The game I'm making has a camera like in Disco Zoo game for android (I'm a newbie)

Comment: Hi Drukalo and welcome to Stack Overflow (SO), your question would probably be better posted on the http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ Stack site, this is focused on Game Development so users are typically able to answer these types of questions better :)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the scene doesn't *really* have a border. You'll need to define the border somehow within your game, then constrain the camera's position with something like [Mathf.Clamp(value, min, max)](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) in an Update() function on the camera.

How can you define the border? It's up to you. Some ideas:

- Hard-code the values in the script that clamps the camera. Probably the quickest option, but not flexible
- Make public parameters on the camera script that let you set min and max positions in the X and Y directions
- If you have a background image: use the extents of that to define your camera's extents
- Create empty objects in your scene that define the minimum and maximum extents of the scene. Put your "min" object at the top-left, and the "max" object at the top-right. Connect it to the camera script, then use those positions to see if you've gone too far in any given direction. The main reason to do this is that it's visual.
- (Slower, but dynamic) If everything in your scene uses physics, you could search the entire scene for every Collider component, then find the furthest extents in each direction. However, this is probably going to be pretty slow (so you'll only want to do it once), it'll take a while to code, and you'll probably want to tweak the boundaries by hand anyway.